# Partial template specialization of overloaded << operator

Tags: c++, template-specialization

I am having trouble to specialize an overloaded << operator template:

The general template is defined as follows:

```
template<typename DocIdType,typename DocType>
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os,
                            const Document<DocIdType,DocType> & doc)
{
   [...]
}
```

The general template works fine. Now I want to specialize the second template parameter. I've tried:

```
template<typename DocIdType>
std::ostream & operator << <DocIdType,std::string> (std::ostream & os,
                           const Document<DocIdType,std::string> & doc)
{
   [...]
}
```

When I try to compile this piece of code I get the following compiler error:
"C2768: Illegal use of explicit template arguments"

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but off the top of my head I'd say function templates can't be partially specialized.

Even if they could, prefer straight overloading.

See also **[Why Not Specialize Function Templates?](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm)** (by Herb Sutter)

---

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91bdc85f9d066813)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename DocIdType,typename DocType>
struct Document {};

template<typename DocIdType>
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const Document<DocIdType,std::string> & doc) {
   return os << "for string";
}

template<typename DocIdType,typename DocType>
std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & os, const Document<DocIdType,DocType> & doc) {
   return os << "for generic";
}

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::cout << Document<struct anything, std::string>() << "\n";
    std::cout << Document<struct anything, struct anything_else>() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
for string
for generic
```